# RequireJS: Should I List All Dependencies for a Module Even If I Know They are Included in Another Module Listed as a Dependency?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

Let's say I have a module called `app.js` whose dependencies look like this:

```
define(['authenticationService', 'userService']);
```

and I have another module whose dependencies look like this:

```
define['app']
```

Should I really list the dependencies as:

```
define['authenticationService', 'userService', 'app']
```

Or do I just assume that the `authenticationService` and `userService` will be included with `app`? What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? This is (probably the biggest) point of AMD: each module should only specify its own dependencies to prevent abstractions from leaking, keep the architecture tidy and make refactoring and testing easier. Seeing a long dependencies list should be a warning flag indicating that the module does too much.

Comment: @kryger, that's exactly my question: "Why would I want to do that?" and "Is this the best way?"